# County area calculated from NLCD (Landcover data) rasters is too large

Tags: r, gis, raster, area

I'm trying to calculate landcover repartition for each US county.
I have obtained NLCD for the Apache county using the FedData package (devtools version) and I'm using county shapefiles from the Census bureau.

The problem is that I get an area that is much larger than the official one and the one indicated in my shapefile, namely 51,000km^2 instead of 29,0000km^2 officially. There must be something I don't understand about the raster object but I'm a very confused after hours of websearching, any help appreciated.

The following describes the code used and the method used to calculate. The county data can be downloaded here:
https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2016/COUNTY/

The following code assumes the county shapefile is saved and unzipped.

1. Get and read the data

```
#devtools::install_github("ropensci/FedData")
library(FedData)
library(rgdal)
library(dplyr)

#Get Apache polygone
counties<- readOGR('tl_2016_us_county/tl_2016_us_county.shp')
apache <- subset(counties,counties$GEOID=="04001")

# Get NCLD data 
nlcd_data <- get_nlcd(apache,
                      year = 2011,
                      label = "Apache",
                      force.redo = TRUE)

nlcd_data #inspect the object, can see that number of cells is around 57 million
```

2. I have then extracted the values of the raster and put them into a frequency table. From there I calculate the resulting area. Since the NLCD data is 30m resolution, I multiply the number of cell of each category by 900 and divide the result by 1 million to obtain the area in Square Kilometer.

The calculated total area is too large.

```
# Calculating the landcover repartition in County
landcover<-data.frame(x2011 = values(nlcd_data)) #Number of rows corresponds to number of cells 
landcover_freq<-table(landcover)

df_landcover <- as.data.frame(landcover_freq)

res <- df_landcover %>%
  mutate(area_type_sqm = Freq*900,
         area_type_km=area_type_sqm/1e6,
         area_sqkm = sum(area_type_km))%>%
  group_by(landcover)%>%
  mutate(pc_land =round(100*area_type_km/area_sqkm,1))

head(arrange(res,desc(pc_land)))

# A tibble: 6 x 6
# Groups:   landcover [6]
  landcover     Freq area_type_sqm area_type_km area_sqkm pc_land
  <fct>        <int>         <dbl>        <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1 52        33455938   30110344200      30110.     51107.    58.9
2 42        16073820   14466438000      14466.     51107.    28.3
3 71         5999412    5399470800       5399.     51107.    10.6
4 31          488652     439786800        440.     51107.     0.9
5 21          362722     326449800        326.     51107.     0.6
6 22           95545      85990500         86.0    51107.     0.2

## Total area calculated from raster is 51,107 square km

apache_area <- as.data.frame(apache) %>%
  mutate(AREA=(as.numeric(ALAND)+as.numeric(AWATER))/1e6) %>%
  select(AREA)

apache_area$AREA
29055.47 #Official area of apache county (in square km)
```

3. Visual inspection of the shapefile and the raster:

The difference doesn't seem large enough to justify the difference

```
apache <- spTransform(apache,proj4string(nlcd_data))
plot(nlcd_data)
plot(apache,add=TRUE)
```

[image: Apache county on NLCD raster]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that you get the data returned in the Mercator projection.

```
crs(nlcd_data)
CRS arguments:
 +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +k=1 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext
+no_defs
```

This coordinate reference system *preserves shape* and that is why it is used for web-mapping. It should not be used for most other purposes, as it is also notorious for *distortion of area*.

The take-home message is to never just trust the nominal resolution of a projected raster and assume that it is correct and/or constant. The *reliable* way to compute area is to use longitude/latitude coordinates, because these are, by definition, not distorted.

The reported spatial resolution is

```
res(nlcd_data)
[1] 30 30
```

So it is not surprising that you expected that the cells have an area of 30 x 30 = 900 m<sup>2</sup>. But the cells sizes are actually between 573 and 625 m<sup>2</sup> for Apache county. Illustrated below.

First get the data

```
library(FedData)
counties <- raster::getData("GADM", country="USA", level=2)
apache <- subset(counties,counties$NAME_2=="Apache")
nlcd <- get_nlcd(apache, year = 2011, label = "nlcd_apache", force.redo = TRUE)

# move to terra
library(terra)
r <- rast(nlcd)
ap <- vect(apache)
# county boundaries to Mercator
apm <- project(ap, crs(r))
```

To compute the area of the grid cells I represent them as polygons. I first aggregate to get much larger cells to avoid getting too many small polygons (it would take very long, and perhaps crash R). I then transform the Mercator polygons to longitude/latitude, compute their true area, and transform back (just for consistent display purposes).

```
f <- 300
a <- aggregate(rast(r), f)
p <- as.polygons(a)

# compute area
g <- project(p, "+proj=longlat")
g$area <- round(expanse(g) / (f * f), 5)

# project back and plot
merc <- project(g, crs(r))
plot(merc, "area", border=NA)
lines(apm)
```

[image]

The map shows the approximate variation in the size of the original "900 m<sup>2</sup>" cells (between 573 and 625). This is not the case when I use the original data, as illustrated below.

```
library(terra)
# "filename" is the local file that has the nlcd data
usnlcd <- rast(filename)
crs(usnlcd, proj4=TRUE)
#[1] "+proj=aea +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"

res(x)
#[1] 30 30
```

Note that `+proj=aea` stands for the *Albers* **Equal Area**  projection!

```
ap <- vect(apache)
apm <- project(ap, crs(usnlcd))
x <- crop(usnlcd, apm)

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(x)
lines(apm)
# gg2 computed as above
plot(gg2, "area", border=NA)
```

As you can see, the cell area is indeed 900 m<sup>2</sup>, with only very little distortion, so small that it can be ignored.

[image]

You could transform the Mercator data back to the original `+proj=aea`, but then you would have degraded the quality of the data twice. So that is a really bad idea. You *could* also account for the true cell area of each cell, but that is rather convoluted.

Finally, to get the area covered by each land cover class

```
m <- mask(x, apm)
f <- freq(m)
f <- data.frame(f)
f$area <- round(f$count * 900 / 1e6, 1)

# the next step is a bit tricky and will be done by `freq` in future versions
levs <- levels(m)[[1]]
f$class <- levs[f$value + 1]
```

Voila:

```
f[, c("class", "area")]
#                           class    area
#1                     Open Water    21.5
#2          Developed, Open Space   175.3
#3       Developed, Low Intensity    46.4
#4    Developed, Medium Intensity     9.7
#5      Developed, High Intensity     1.0
#6                    Barren Land   232.5
#7               Deciduous Forest    44.6
#8               Evergreen Forest  7604.6
#9                   Mixed Forest     2.0
#10                   Shrub/Scrub 18262.8
#11                   Herbaceuous  2514.4
#12                   Hay/Pasture     1.9
#13              Cultivated Crops     0.0
#14                Woody Wetlands    38.8
#15 Emergent Herbaceuous Wetlands    53.6
```

And the total is as expected

```
sum(f$area)
#[1] 29009.1
```

PS. This problem has now been solved at the source --- but I hope this answer will remain useful for others using spatial data with a Mercator CRS.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. I am not familiar with the terra library so this code is currently arcane for me but I'll work through it. 

Would you please confirm that I understand this right: 
A better way to achieve what I'm trying to do is to use the original nlcd data, transform my shapefile according to the crs of the original nlcd data, crop the county and do the calculations from there?

Comment: Yes. And after `crop` you can use `mask(x, apm)` to set the cells outside of Apache to NA.

Answer (score 3):

Y'all, thanks so much for catching this, and thanks [Robert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/635245/robert-hijmans) for alerting me on Github! I hadn't realized that WCS was serving up transformed data. Luckily, the MRLC has made the data available in its native format as well, so I've gone ahead and pushed an update to FedData that provides those data (in CONUS Albers).

FWIW (no pictures, because this is my first SO post):

```r
#devtools::install_github("ropensci/FedData")
library(FedData)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(tigris)
library(raster)

#Get Apache polygon
apache <- 
  tigris::counties(state = "AZ") %>%
  dplyr::filter(NAME == "Apache")

# Get NCLD data 
nlcd_data <- 
  FedData::get_nlcd(
    template = apache,
    year = 2011,
    label = "Apache",
    force.redo = TRUE
  )

# Transform Apache polygon to NLCD CRS
apache %<>%
  sf::st_transform(raster::crs(nlcd_data))

# Plot NLCD raster and transformed Apache polygon
raster::plot(nlcd_data)

apache %>%
  sf::st_geometry() %>%
  plot(border = "white", lwd = 2, add = TRUE)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSGpq.png

```r
# Mask NLCD data by Apache County (and plot result)
nlcd_data %<>%
  raster::mask(apache)
plot(nlcd_data)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhFvS.png

```r
# Table of areas in km^2
nlcd_data_table <-
  nlcd_data %>%
  values() %>%
  tibble::tibble(landcover = .) %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  dplyr::group_by(landcover) %>%
  count(name = "freq") %>%
  dplyr::mutate(area = (freq * 900) %>%
                  units::set_units("m^2") %>%
                  units::set_units("km^2"))
nlcd_data_table
#> # A tibble: 15 x 3
#> # Groups:   landcover [15]
#>    landcover     freq       area
#>        <int>    <int>     [km^2]
#>  1        11    24134    21.7206
#>  2        21   194720   175.2480
#>  3        22    51321    46.1889
#>  4        23    10485     9.4365
#>  5        24     1069     0.9621
#>  6        31   259987   233.9883
#>  7        41    48906    44.0154
#>  8        42  8456196  7610.5764
#>  9        43     2179     1.9611
#> 10        52 19941185 17947.0665
#> 11        71  3190650  2871.5850
#> 12        81     2169     1.9521
#> 13        82        4     0.0036
#> 14        90    42628    38.3652
#> 15        95    59014    53.1126

# Total area NLCD raster:
sum(nlcd_data_table$area)
#> 29056.18 [km^2]

# Area of Apache county
apache %>%
  sf::st_area() %>%
  units::set_units("km^2")
#> 29056.19 [km^2]
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>