# Is this flow to extract the area of all pixels > 2 within a polygon layer, correct?

Tags: r, area, r-raster

Goal: Extract the area in km2 of pixels that have values > 2 within a polygon. Values are not reflecting real country areas.

```
library(sf)
library(raster)
library(exactextractr)

# Generate raster 

r <- raster::raster(matrix(0:7, ncol=10), xmn=0, ymn=0, xmx=10, ymx=10)

poly <- sf::st_as_sfc('POLYGON ((2 2, 7 6, 4 9, 2 2))')

#In my case I need a CRS that is valid for multiple countries in the Americas and allows me to estimate area in km2- epsg:3857

crs(r) <- "+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs"

poly<-st_set_crs(poly,"+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs")

#Extract area of pixels that have values > 2. This is in particular what I'm interested in, is my function argument doing what I say it does.

ext<-exact_extract(r,poly,function(values, coverage_fraction)
                                          length(values > 2)) #6 values

#Determine pixel size

res(r) #1 10
res.m2<-10
res.km2<-res.m2/1000000
  
#Determine area in km2:multiply number of pixels >2 by the pixel area

tot.area<-res.km2*ext
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your statement that you

> need a CRS that is valid for multiple countries in the
> Americas and allows me to estimate area in km2- epsg:3857

seems based on the common misconception that you cannot use longitude/latitude data to determine area sizes ([here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/396012/8993) is some discussion).

In fact, longitude/latitude is a great coordinate reference system to measure area. You *can* use *some* projections (planar coordinate reference systems), but most projections distort area. So if you were to use one, you would need to use an equal-area projection (e.g. cylindrical equal-area).

Do **not** use the Mercator projection (`"+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137`, epsg:3857). Mercator conserves shape, and that is why it is used in web-mapping. It also makes Greenland larger than Africa; and you cannot use it to compute area. More discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67711245/635245)

It is generally best to not project raster data (there is quality loss). So here are some very similar work-flows that avoid that. First with `terra` and then with `raster` and `exactextractr` that compute what you are after.

Example data

```
library(terra)
p <- vect('POLYGON ((2 2, 7 6, 4 9, 2 2))')
r <- rast(nrows=10, ncols=10, xmin=0, ymin=0, xmax=10, ymax=10)
r <- init(r, -2:7)
```

Compute area of each cell and combine with the values used

```
a <- cellSize(r, unit="km")
ra <- c(r, a)
names(ra) <- c("values", "area")
```

Extract, subset, and computed sum

```
e <- extract(ra, p, exact=TRUE)
e <- e[e$values>2, ]
sum(e$area * e$fraction)
# [1] 44069.83
```

Alternatively

```
x <- ifel(r>2, r, NA)
a <- cellSize(r, unit="km")
ax <- mask(a, x)
ee <- extract(ax, p, exact=TRUE)
sum(ee$area * ee$fraction, na.rm=TRUE)
#[1] 44069.83
```

With `raster` you can do something similar

```
library(raster)
rr <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10, xmn=0, ymn=0, xmx=10, ymx=10)
values(rr) <- rep(-2:7, 10)
ps <- sf::st_as_sfc('POLYGON ((2 2, 7 6, 4 9, 2 2))')
ps <- as(ps, "Spatial")
crs(ps) <- crs(rr)

aa <- area(rr)
s <- stack(aa, rr)
names(s) <- c("area", "values")
v <- extract(s, ps, exact=TRUE, weights=TRUE, normalizeWeights=FALSE)
v <- as.data.frame(v[[1]])
v <- v[v$values > 2, ] 
sum(v$area * v$weight)
# [1] 44056.61
```

Explicitly calling `exactextractr`

```
ext <- exactextractr::exact_extract(s, ps) 
ext <- ext[[1]]
ext <- ext[ext$values > 2, ] 
sum(ext$area * ext$coverage_fraction)
#[1] 44056.61
```

Here is a nice way in which you can use `exactextractr`

```
w <- rr > 2
ext <- exactextractr::exact_extract(aa, ps, weights=w, fun="weighted_sum") 
ext
# [1] 44056.61
```

Comment: So glad I asked, thank you (can't visibly vote the answer).  I had to create the polygon as I had done with 'sf' instead of 'terra' because I couldn't update 'terra' to the version that contains the cellSize function.

Comment: For exactextractr I would recommend `exact_extract(r, poly, function(value, area) sum(area[value > 2]), coverage_area = TRUE)`. This avoids precomputing `frac > 2` which could be significant if we are working in a small part of a large raster. The `coverage_area` flag gives us a covered cell area (computed on the sphere) instead of a coverage fraction and avoids the need to create an area raster for weighting.